# Receive circular reference error from AWS S3 Select query using s3api to count lines in a file in S3

Tags: amazon-s3-select

I'm trying to count the number of lines in a file stored in an S3 bucket using [AWS SELECT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectSELECTContent.html).  Specifically, executing the following command (based upon [AWS s3api documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/select-object-content.html) and this [Java example for the count(*) query](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-i-used-amazon-s3-select-query-selective-data-stored-sharma/)):

```
aws s3api select-object-content --bucket my_bucket_name --key my_file_name --expression "select count(*) from S3object s" --expression-type SQL --input-serialization CSV={}  --output-serialization CSV={}
```

The above returns:

```
{
    "Payload":
Circular reference detected
```

Even though the defaults work for my use case, I tried providing additional information with the `CSV={}` parameters in the command line and also tried the alternative JSON syntax `'{"CSV":{}}'`. Always receive the `Circular reference detected` error.

The file exists in the bucket; otherwise, you get a `NoSuchKey` error.  Yeah, been there, done that... :)

Examples for AWS SELECT are either rare or my Google-fu is failing me.

Suggestions?  Alternatives welcome, but they must be scriptable.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if someone still facing the error - updating awscli helped in my case - pip3 install awscli --upgrade